# Anet A8 - first couple of layer are trash

Tags: print-quality, anet-a8, layer-height

I just got an Anet A8 and I'm pretty happy with it except for one small detail:

[image: First layers of a print]

All my prints start like this. I tried to :

- pre-heat the printer ❌
- add a smaller height of the first layer ❌

I’m kinda new to this and i did not find a correct answer to my problem so here’s my Cura configuration:

[image: Cura config]

Comment: Try to adjust the Z offset.

Comment: First off all your bed temp is way to high. Put it down to 50 or so. Second is that you should really put some time into leveling your bed properly. I had tons of problems with this and after sitting down for 10/15 minutes doing everything over and over again. I had amazing adhesion and i could print 10 or so prints before having to do it again. Since then i upgraded to an auto leveling sensor. Also support can be disabled for the print in the picture its totally not needed.

Comment: A phone picture of your computer screen showing your Cura setting isn't exactly the easiest to read or most accessible way of sharing those settings. Consider converting the image to text.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden thank you for your advice, i will apply it to my next post, since this topic was helpful enough to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is bed leveling.

I recently got my Anet A8 and the biggest kill for my print quality is bed leveling. If its too far from the nozzle, I get something like your picture. You might want to try the paper test where you manually move the nozzle to each corner of the bed and adjust the bed till the paper cannot move freely between the bed and nozzle.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be *leveling* per se but rather the distance between the bed and nozzle being too great (the bed might be perfectly *level*, but just too far from the nozzle).

Comment: @TomvanderZanden  nailed it.  That stringiness is a sure indicator that the first layer is about 25% of a layer thickness too high

Comment: @TomvanderZanden you were right !!!!

Comment: @TomvanderZanden Huh, your right that the term "bed leveling" may not have been perfect but if you read my answer, I talked about the bed being too far from the nozzle and gave the solution of adjusting bed screws to raise the bed to meet the paper test. Aside from that you can lower the heatblock/nozzle by unscrewing a bit from the motor. Or by lowering the z-endstop. Well either way I am glad OP has fixed their issue.